# How to delete the Custom app where it is throwing me following errors

Tags: salesforce1-app, force.com, lightning-apps, custom, app

When i clicked on setup and then following APPS their i found this edit|del when i want to delete my app it is throwing me error that "Unable to Delete the Custom App Profiles are using this custom app as default"[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will have to reassign a different default app to each of these profiles by navigating to **Setup > Profiles > [click a profile name] > Assigned Apps > Edit** and selecting a new default app.

(If you are not using the Enhanced Profile User Interface, then the click path is **Setup > Profiles > [click a profile name] > Custom App Settings > Edit**)